# How is unsafe.cpp linked to Unsafe.java in the openJDK build system

Tags: c++, java

I've cloned unsafe.cpp and Unsafe.java to custom versions. I've got the new JVM to build but it seems that my UnsafeNew.java is being inlined with the unsafe.cpp methods and not my new unsafenew.cpp methods.

Hoping someone with expertise in the openJDK build system know how this is tied together.

Thanks

Tomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least in openJDK 7 the answer is that it's hardcoded into the build system. While regular JNI requires a LoadLibrary() call, for Unsafe and a handful of other files this is done by the compiler.

In  hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/nativeLookup.cpp there is an array called

```
JNINativeMethod lookup_special_native_methods[]
```

that includes

```
{ CC"Java_sun_misc_Unsafe_registerNatives",NULL, FN_PTR(JVM_RegisterUnsafeMethods)}
```

This does the trick.

I hope I helped someone with this.

Tomer